# Bash Script - test -s true on empty file?

Tags: bash, scripting

So I am getting confused by this one and cannot really understand why this is happening. Was hoping someone here could enlighten me!

I have a `grep` that is pushing its results to a file called `out`. I then have the following code....

```
if [ -s out ]; then
   xargs -n1 basename < out
else
   echo "NO FILES EXIST"
fi
```

The if path works file but when file size is `0` it will not go down the else path...

I then tried this...

```
if [ ! -s out ]; then
   xargs -n1 basename < out
else
   echo "NO FILES EXIST"
fi
```

And everything works as expected but in reverse (obviously)...

So my question is, what is the `-s` flag doing behind the scenes that I am not aware of? This completely blew my mind to quite honest. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

---

Output from an `ls -lrt` - file is NOT going down else path here. If I add the `!` operator the file will however go down the if path path and then if the file fills it will go down the else path.

```
0 Jul 30 12:15 out
```

---

No luck with the suggestion of making $filename a variable and passing it around that way. I was thinking maybe it has something to do with my `grep`? The entire code is as follows:

```
grep -l 'TimeStamp: '$2'/'$3'/'$1 $ARCHIVE/*/* > $filename
if [ -s "$filename" ]; then
   xargs -n1 basename < out
else
   echo "NO FILES EXIST"
fi
```

Where $1,$2,$3 is yyyy,mm,dd respectively.

The other thought I had is it might be my machine? I am running Linux Ubuntu 3.2.0-58-generic.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls -l out` or `stat out` when the file is reproducing the unexpected behavior? If it contained only whitespace -- say, a single newline -- that would explain the behavior you're seeing. Granted, you're describing it as 0-byte, but the obvious explanation would be that it's not actually 0-byte even when it appears empty.

Comment: ...by the way, `[` is the command also known as `test` (literally, `/bin/[` is a symlink to `/bin/test`, and whereas your shell almost certainly provides a builtin version, that builtin version is required to be compatible), so `[ -s out ]` is the thing documented in `man test` as `test -s`... making more of this a generic-UNIX-tools question than a bash question as such.

Comment: I would think that by adding the not flag which triggers both logical paths that the file is correctly being seen as a not a zero sized file and then as not a filled file. Logically speaking, the reverse should then also be true and would trigger both paths.

Comment: Anyhow -- cannot reproduce. `rm out; touch out; if [ -s out ]; then xargs -n1 basename <out; else echo "NO FILES EXIST"; fi` correctly emits `NO FILES EXIST`. If you can provide a standalone reproducer that actually, well, reproduces the problem, that might be helpful.

Comment: Are you literally using the word `out` in the `[` test? Or are you using a variable (like `$outputfile`)?

Comment: What happens if you replace the `xargs` with another `echo` (e.g. `echo "Files exist"`)?  (I don't expect the behaviour to change, but eliminating `xargs` and `basename` simplifies the script.)  Can you show a script with both tests on a single file, and then run it under `-x` (`bash -x your-script.sh empty-file` and `bash -x your-script.sh nonempty-file`).  If you can't see the pattern, post the output.  Which platform are you on? Which version of Bash are you using?

Comment: @EtanReisner has a very good clue, there -- if you were using, say, `$filename`, but that variable were empty, bash would be running `[ -s ]`, which is equivalent to `[ -n -s ]`, which is true. All the more reasons to always use quotes; `[ -s "$filename" ]` wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: `for file in "$@"; do ls -l "$file"; if [ -s "$file" ]; then echo "1: File $file is non-empty"; else echo "1: File $file is empty"; fi; if [ ! -s "$file" ]; then echo "2: File $file is empty"; else echo "2: File $file is non-empty"; fi; done` and save it as `the-script.sh` and run: `echo "Hi" > nonempty-file; cp /dev/null empty-file; bash -x the-script.sh empty-file nonempty-file`.

Comment: This all works as expected for me.  Are you sure you're running it in `bash`?

Comment: (The suggestion wasn't that making `filename` a variable would help, by the way -- it was that if you were _actually_ using a variable, but showing it to us as if it were a static file, that could be the cause of your problem, and an explanation of why we can't reproduce it by running the code you provide us. Again, we need a standalone reproducer -- something we can copy and paste to get the same behavior -- to help here, and as of this writing I don't think you've provided one).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...by the way, it's not the cause of your immediate problem, but `$1'/'$2'/'$3` is asking for bugs compared to `"$1/$2/$3"`; the former has no quotes around its expansions, and so those expansions get string-split and glob-expanded. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Prevent_field_splitting_and_ignore_glob_pattern_characters

Comment: (on a related side note, `$ARCHIVE/*/*` is a little trickier to do correctly; it's written as `"$ARCHIVE"/*/*` to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion within the archive's name, but to ensure that glob expansion happens with the wildcard characters).

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce it. Can you follow these steps:

```
touch test.txt
[ -s "test.txt" ] && echo "empty"
```

?

---

Btw, this might be more a question for clearance than an answer and could be a comment, I just wanted to have both commands as readable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
-s FILE:         True if file exists and is not empty
```

You mentioned the file exists, and that its size is zero, so the test should be `True`.

**Try using the full path to the file**, not just `out`.  e.g.>

```
if [ -s /full/path/to/out ]; then
   xargs -n1 basename < out
else
   echo "NO FILES EXIST"
fi
```

I think the problem is not the test itself, but the path where the script was ran.

Comment: ...and if that's the case, the question this is in answer to lacks a MCVE / SSCCE and should be closed (for not containing enough information or code to reproduce the problem).